Issues with Paging in Firestore: Always Starts from the Beginning
 override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<DocumentSnapshot>): LoadResult<DocumentSnapshot, Diary> {
        return try {
            val couple = authRepo.getCouple() ?: return LoadResult.Error(Exception("Couple ID is null"))

            val query = firestore
                .collection("pairs")
                .document(couple.id)
                .collection("diaries")
                .whereEqualTo("pinned", false)
                .orderBy("date", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                .apply {
                    if (params.key != null) {
                        startAfter(params.key)
                    }
                }.limit(params.loadSize.toLong() + 1)

            val snapshot = query.get().await()

            val diaryEntities = snapshot.documents.mapNotNull { doc ->
                doc.toObject(DiaryEntity::class.java)?.copy(id = doc.id)
            }

            val newDiaryList = diaryEntities.mapNotNull { diaryEntity ->
                val images = diaryRepository.getImagesByDiary(diaryEntity.id)
                val audio = diaryRepository.getAudioByDiary(diaryEntity.id)
                val user = authRepo.getUserById(diaryEntity.userId)?.toDiaryUser()

                user?.let {
                    Diary(
                        id = diaryEntity.id,
                        coupleId = diaryEntity.coupleId,
                        title = encryption.decrypt(diaryEntity.title, couple.secretKey),
                        description = encryption.decrypt(diaryEntity.description, couple.secretKey),
                        date = diaryEntity.date,
                        createdAt = diaryEntity.createdAt,
                        pinned = diaryEntity.pinned,
                        user = user,
                        updatedAt = diaryEntity.updatedAt,
                        seenAt = diaryEntity.seenAt,
                        images = images,
                        audio = audio
                    )
                }
            }

            val lastVisible = snapshot.documents.lastOrNull()
            LoadResult.Page(
                data = newDiaryList,
                prevKey = null,
                nextKey = lastVisible
            )
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            LoadResult.Error(e)
        }
    }

I'm working on a diary application using Firestore and Paging in Jetpack Compose. I've implemented a PagingSource to load diary entries, but I keep encountering an issue where the data always starts from the beginning, regardless of the pagination state.
